# Ubuntu Server 12.10 No GUI Headless Boot and/or Reboot

Tags: gui, monitor, reboot, headless

I have a headless server running the latest Ubuntu Server 12.10. It does not have any GUI at all.

I am having the same issue that others are having which is that when you boot or reboot without a monitor (headless) the computer does not boot.

The solution presented to others was to edit their `xorg.conf` file. But since I do not want a GUI installed (and therefore chose not to install a GUI after installing Ubuntu 12.10) I do not have a `xorg.conf` file in the `/etc/X11/` directory.

Ubuntu is a widely used distro of Linux, especially for server applications, I absolutely love it. Therefore, there has to be someone who solved this already?

Comment: few thoughs: what happens when you connect a monitor after turning it on (at what stage it is stuck)? are you sure this is not BIOS related? does your computer behaves the same with other operating systems? i have a headless server that always boots without a monitor

Comment: I am on a PowerMac G5. It doesn't have a BIOS. It's hard to tell at what stage it gets stuck at because when I plug in a monitor the monitor doesn't turn on. When I research this problem, others have it too on other systems.

Comment: Thanks for any help! I would love to solve this problem!

Comment: Could you link to the solutions you are talking about // explain why you think this problem is the same? If the solution had something to do with xorg, then the system of those users would have booted (it reads that file fairly late) -> if that is actually the same issue, you probably do have something that boots. If you are sure you don't boot at all, it's probably not the same issue, so the mention of xorg only confuses the problem -> maybe add some information. Does it boot with a keyboard and/or monitor attached? (see @halim 's answer), does it beep, etc etc.

Comment: Ok, I will go back and find the other solutions and I will try to find a way to see if the OS is actually booting.

Answer (score 2):

I have the same problem. when I first installed Ubuntu 12 server edition, there was no problem but after a month it will not boot without monitor and keyboard.

What I did is to check the BIOS and change the boot options from 'do not boot with errors to boot with errors'

After that my server can boot headless with no monitor or keyboard attached. It seems that the BIOS will not allow booting if there is an error such as no monitor or no keyboard. By allowing the server to ignore any errors, it will boot.